# Trigonometry sum 1

Tags: sequences-and-series, trigonometry

For $n \ge 1$, let $G_n$ be the geometric mean of $\{\sin(\pi k/(2n) : 1 \le k \le n\}$.
Then $\lim_{n\to\infty}
G_n$ is
(A) $1/4$ (B) $\log 2$ (C) $1/
2
\log 2$ (D) $1/2$.

My approach:
$$G_n^n =\prod_{k=1}^{n-1} \cos(\pi k/2n)\tan(\pi k/2n)\sin(\pi/2) = \prod_{k=1}^{ n-1}\cos(\pi k/2n)$$ here I am stuck

Answer (score 1):

Observe that
$$\ln G_n=\frac1n\sum_{k=1}^n\ln\sin\left(\frac{k\pi}{2n}\right).$$
This is more-or-less a Riemann sum for the integral
$$\int_0^1\ln\sin\left(\frac{\pi x}2\right)\,dx.$$

Comment: but what is proof of the value it equals to?

Comment: How do we evaluate integration?